Inserting special characters like x̄ X̄ that aren't in the digraph table?
x̄ is a character in statistics to represent the mean. When I look in the digraph table, I can see the character Ā - LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH MACRON, as well as ā.
However, I couldn't figure out how to insert x̄ or X̄

The issue with x̄ is that it's actually made of two separate characters, U+0078 (lowercase x) followed by U+0304 "Combining Macron".
The Vim digraph system can only be used to insert a single Unicode character, so you can't get it to use a single digraph to insert both characters.
But you could create a digraph to insert the Combining Macron itself, for example:
:digraph __ 772

(772 is the decimal value for hexadecimal 0x304, which matches the U+0304 code point. You can also pick a digraph sequence different from __ that you prefer.)
And then you can use x Ctrl+K _ _ to insert x̄, or Y Ctrl+K _ _ to insert Ȳ or add the Combining Macron to any other character.

When finding a character you don't know how to type with Vim, paste it into the editor and inspect it with ga.
In case it's something that can be expressed as a digraph, Vim will tell you so, e.g. consider ē:
<ē> 275, Hex 0113, Oct 423, Digr e-

For x̄, this yields a different result:
<x>  120,  Hex 78,  Octal 170 < ̄> 772, Hex 0304, Octal 1404

Lucky for us, filbranden already did the research and we know we have to type 'x' followed by U+0304.
The general way to insert an arbitrary unicode character is with Ctrl-VU as explained in :help i_CTRL-V_digit.
The following will insert an x̄:
x<C-V>u0304

The leading zero can also be omitted:
x<C-V>u304

Having to type so much for a single character quickly becomes clumsy.
When you need to use one (or two) special characters over and over, consider creating an abbreviation for them.
Luckily, Ctrl-V works the same in Command-line mode.
:iabbrev <buffer> x- x̄
:iabbrev <buffer> X- X̄

This is much faster—just type x-  and it will be replaced—but you'll have to define an abbreviation for each character.
Using abbreviations doesn't scale but it's convenient if your character set is limited.
By the way, I chose buffer-local abbreviations so you can define them only for your buffer on statistics.
More on abbreviations can be found with :help abbreviations.
